# Why does color matter for PET recycling but not for HDPE recycling?

Tags: recycling, plastic

Why does color matter for PET recycling but not for HDPE recycling? I'm not sure about other countries, but in the place I live in the recycling plant that receives PET from recycling bins I use only works with certain colors (blue, brown, green, colorless) whereas HDPE's color has no relevance. And the Russian recyclers are [annoyed](https://telegra.ph/Vtoraya-zhizn-plastika-kak-pererabatyvat-bolshe-polimerov-06-18) with other PET colors, they want to confine them to those four only. But HDPE colors are not a problem. Why? It has something to do with the types of final products, I'm told